# jQuery - toggleClass of DIV when link is clicked, hide link, and show hidden info within DIV. Multiple instances on page

Tags: html, addclass, removeclass, jquery

My overall goal starts with having a product page displaying multiple product pictures within the `productLayout` DIV. Then, the link within that DIV will add a class `pL100` which expands the width of the DIV to show hidden content that is hidden within the `hidden` DIV. I would then want the initial product picture to disappear and the hidden DIV be visible. Within that hidden DIV I want a link to hide that DIV again and bring back the original DIV with the photo. However, I want all of this to toggle based on if someone clicks on another product to expand that product. If they do that, I would want the open DIV to remove the `pL100` class to be shown as it was initially.

As of right now, I have all of the toggling down to close the other DIVs when different DIVs are clicked on; however, I need help with hiding the initial content as well as adding a link within the hidden content to remove the added class to go back to normal. As well as having all of that toggle if other DIVs are clicked on.

I would also like to animate the "expanding" and "closing" of the DIVs so it's not so abrupt. Not sure if I can do that because I'm using `addClass` and `removeClass`, but if there is a way with doing it all differently, then I'd love to know how.

If you notice, I am calling every 4th `productLayout` DIV to remove the marrgin on the right with `.productLayout:nth-of-type(4n+0)` so it sits nicely in the `container` DIV. However, when a `productLayout` DIV is clicked, all of the DIVs shift down (which is what I want) but then each 4th `productLayout` DIV is now pushed against the next DIV. Is there any way to add back in the margin but then apply it to the new 4th `productLayout` DIV in that row?

I hope this all makes sense, and sorry if I'm not clear. I really appreciate any help, and if I'm doing something wrong please advise. Thank you so much.

**Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/pT3DC/**

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.productLayout a').on('click', function(){
$(this).closest('div').toggleClass('pL100').siblings().removeClass('pL100');
$(this).closest('div').children('.hidden').toggleClass('hide').siblings().removeClass('hide');
});
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="productLayout">
    <p><a href="#" class="showMore">Show More 1</a></p>
    <div class="hidden hide">this is hidden content</div>
</div>
<div class="productLayout">
    <p><a href="#" class="showMore">Show More 2</a></p>
    <div class="hidden hide">this is hidden content</div>
</div>
<div class="productLayout">
    <p><a href="#" class="showMore">Show More 3</a></p>
    <div class="hidden hide">this is hidden content</div>
</div>
<div class="productLayout">
    <p><a href="#" class="showMore">Show More 4</a></p>
    <div class="hidden hide">this is hidden content</div>
</div>
<div class="productLayout">
    <p><a href="#" class="showMore">Show More 5</a></p>
    <div class="hidden hide">this is hidden content</div>
</div>
<div class="productLayout">
    <p><a href="#" class="showMore">Show More 6</a></p>
    <div class="hidden hide">this is hidden content</div>
</div>
<div class="productLayout">
    <p><a href="#" class="showMore">Show More 7</a></p>
    <div class="hidden hide">this is hidden content</div>
</div>
<div class="productLayout">
    <p><a href="#" class="showMore">Show More 8</a></p>
    <div class="hidden hide">this is hidden content</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
width: 1000px;
padding: 0px 16px; 
}
.productLayout {
width: 228px;
float: left;
margin: 0px 16px 16px 0px;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #333333;
}   
.productLayout:nth-of-type(4n+0) {
margin-right: 0px;
}
.pL100 {
width: 936px;
padding: 16px;
color: #000000;
float: left;
margin: 0px 16px 16px 0px;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #333333;
}
.hide {
display:none;
}
.hidden {
clear: both;
width: 100%;
background-color: #000000;
color: #FFFFFF;        
}
```

**Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/pT3DC/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

**Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pT3DC/3/)**

---

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.productLayout:nth-of-type(4n+0)').addClass('marginFix');

    $("div .productLayout .show").click(function () {
        $('div .marginFix').removeClass('marginFix');

        $('div .pL100').removeClass('pL100');
        $('.show').removeClass('hide');
        $('div .hidden').addClass('hide');

        $(this).addClass('hide');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('hide');
        $(this).parent().addClass('pL100');

        // `this` is the DOM element that was clicked
        var index = $("div .show").index(this) + 1;
        $('.productLayout:nth-of-type(4n+' + index + ')').addClass('marginFix');
    });

    $("div .productLayout .hidden").click(function () {
        $('div .marginFix').removeClass('marginFix');
        $('.productLayout:nth-of-type(4n+0)').addClass('marginFix');

        $('div .pL100').removeClass('pL100');
        $('.show').removeClass('hide');
        $('div .hidden').addClass('hide');

        $(this).siblings().removeClass('pL100');
    });
});
```

---

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 0px 16px;
}
.productLayout {
    width: 228px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 16px 16px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
}
.marginFix {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.pL100 {
    width: 936px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: #000000;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 16px 16px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
}
.hide {
    display:none;
}
.hidden {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="productLayout">
        <p class="show">
            <a href="#" class="showMore">Show More 1</a>
        </p>
        <div class="hidden hide">this is hidden content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="productLayout">
        <p class="show">
            <a href="#" class="showMore">Show More 2</a>
        </p>
        <div class="hidden hide">this is hidden content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="productLayout">
        <p class="show">
            <a href="#" class="showMore">Show More 3</a>
        </p>
        <div class="hidden hide">this is hidden content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="productLayout">
        <p class="show">
            <a href="#" class="showMore">Show More 4</a>
        </p>
        <div class="hidden hide">this is hidden content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="productLayout">
        <p class="show">
            <a href="#" class="showMore">Show More 5</a>
        </p>
        <div class="hidden hide">this is hidden content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="productLayout">
        <p class="show">
            <a href="#" class="showMore">Show More 6</a>
        </p>
        <div class="hidden hide">this is hidden content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="productLayout">
        <p class="show">
            <a href="#" class="showMore">Show More 7</a>
        </p>
        <div class="hidden hide">this is hidden content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="productLayout">
        <p class="show">
            <a href="#" class="showMore">Show More 8</a>
        </p>
        <div class="hidden hide">this is hidden content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks like it fixed the toggling hiding of the hidden DIV, which is great. Any other input would be awesome. Also the fiddle you linked to is mine and not an updated one. fyi. thanks.

Comment: @Scott Updated...Does everything I can think of but that doesn't mean it will make you happy.  The second click event binding is your "hide" just bind it to a link you put inside the "show" `DIV` if you want it to be a hide link.  This will only let one show at a time. Also `nth-of-type` isn't supported in all browsers, to fix that do something like https://github.com/keithclark/JQuery-Extended-Selectors

Comment: Very very awesome stuff. It is almost everything I asked for (and more) and I truly appreciate it! I will work on getting the "hide link" figured out. In regards to my question about animating the "show" and "hide", is that possible with this set up? Just a simple animation so it doesn't just shut and close. Let me know what you think. Thank you so much again!!